# How can I get rid of the 'WARNING: Installing to ~/.gem since ... and ... aren't both writable." warning?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I *like* that it installs into `~/.gem`, I just wish it would stop warning me about it.

Setting a `$GEM_HOME` doesn't seem like a solution, since I use both `gem18` and `gem19` (I've got to support both), and I like that the gems for each install into `~/.gem/ruby/<version>`, and when I set a `$GEM_HOME` gems for each get installed in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)? Especially if you play with multiple ruby versions. For me the biggest bonus is project specific gemsets with automatic switching.